# CSP Configuration not allowing for proper loading of assets

Tags: javascript, http, security, content-security-policy

I am having an issue with configuration here. Im trying to apply an accurate CSP policy, and it keeps throwing errors when trying to load my react app.

My CSP Policy

```
"script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-rAnd0m123' 'unsafe-inline' https://staging.example.org staging.example.org example.org *.example.org *.gstatic.com *.googleapis.com *.google.com *.amazonaws.com *.myservice.io google-analytics.com *.google-analytics.com *.algolianet.com algolianet.com algolia.net *.algolia.net http: https:;
object-src 'none';
base-uri example.org *.example.org;
require-trusted-types-for 'script';
report-uri 'none';
font-src https://staging.example.org staging.example.org example.org *.example.org *.gstatic.com *.googleapis.com *.google.com *.amazonaws.com *.myservice.io google-analytics.com *.google-analytics.com *.algolianet.com algolianet.com algolia.net *.algolia.net;
manifest-src 'self' https://staging.example.org staging.example.org example.org *.example.org *.gstatic.com *.googleapis.com *.google.com *.amazonaws.com *.myservice.io google-analytics.com *.google-analytics.com *.algolianet.com algolianet.com algolia.net *.algolia.net"
```

The Error

```
Refused to load the script 'https://staging.example.org/static/js/2.d7.chunk.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-rAnd0m123' 'unsafe-inline' {... } 'strict-dynamic' is present, so host-based allowlisting is disabled. Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I have tried to set script-src-elem to example.org and the many variations that I have applied above, but I am still being met with this error.

note: its not example.org, just replacing my website.

Comment: You'll find benefit in one of the many CSP validators: https://cspvalidator.org/#url=https://cspvalidator.org/, or https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com, or [seespee](https://github.com/papandreou/seespee), etc.

Comment: I've used them, and its telling me that this is a valid CSP. However, the app wont load this way. It keep sending that error.

Comment: It is not possible to validate your URL on [CSP Validator](https://cspvalidator.org/#url=https://cspvalidator.org/) with your exact CSP and have it pass if it fails in a browser. It seems there is an inconsistency that is unclear.

Comment: **'strict-dynamic' is present, so host-based allowlisting is disabled** - I suggest removing 'strict-dynamic'

Answer (score 1):

'strict-dynamic' [cancells](http://csplite.com/csp/test217/) all host based sources (http: https: inclusive). Therefore you nedd to allow these sources by the 'nonce' token:

```
<script src="https://staging.example.org/static/js/2.d7.chunk.js" nonce="rAnd0m123">
```

as all inline `<scrpt>` blocks (because 'strict-dynamic' cancells 'unsafe-inline' token too):

```
<script nonce="rAnd0m123">
   // some code here
</scrpt>
```

> 

Also the report-uri does not support 'none' token, so directive will be ignored.

And you have some extra:

- `staging.example.org` host-source is covered by `*.example.org` in the font-src/script-src/manifest-src directives
- `https://staging.example.org`: is covered by `https:` in the script-src directive
- `http: https:` alltogether covers any host-based sources (except sources which use ws: or wss:)